# Index search and search time

Tags: indexing, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I just started a course on data structure and in the otes it states:

Lets say we have an idex of names (in alphabetical order) ad we want to search if a specific name exists, then the time for the name search is going to be

T(n)-log(n)

Shouldn't it be just log(n)? Is it just a typo instead of T(n)=log(n) ?

Sorry for the naive question but I just want to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct in your understanding.

Comment: Yes it's only a typo and to be more precise if it would have been the complexity that you are assuming it would have been written like -  **nlog(n)**  or **n - log(n)**